# How to display value in combobox and save its id into database

Tags: java, javafx

I have a combobox that the value is shown instead of Id. id should be then insert into a database. I added a listener to combobox to get the Id. By sysout I can see but how could I insert into database????

here is the code:

```
public void comboboxpersonneldata() {
    comboboxpersonnellist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    handler = new DBHandler();
    connection = handler.getConnection();
    try {
        rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT num_personnel,nom_personnel FROM personnel");
        while (rs.next()) {
            // comboboxpersonnellist.add(rs.getInt(1));
            comboboxpersonnellist.addAll(new comboboxPersonnel(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2)));
        }
        combopersonnel.setItems(comboboxpersonnellist);
        combopersonnel.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> {
            if (newval != null) {
                System.out.println(newval.getNum_personnel());
            }
        });

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        rs.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and the model class:

```
public class comboboxPersonnel {
    int num_personnel;
    String name_personnel;

    public comboboxPersonnel(int num_personnel, String name_personnel) {
        this.num_personnel = num_personnel;
        this.name_personnel = name_personnel;
    }

    public int getNum_personnel() {
        return num_personnel;
    }

    public String getName_personnel() {
        return name_personnel;
    }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return name_personnel;
     }

}
```

Comment: Use a `INSERT` query (or a `UPDATE` query, if you merely want to update a table row)...

Comment: Of course there is a method that insert details into database with other fields. but now what I need is how to take the result of combobox listenning because it is showing only now.

Comment: Any help?? How to get the value of the combobox showing value but saving its I'd into database. I stuck only on inserting id.

Comment: Write clearly, what you want to do: insert only id (or entity) into another table, update selected item in "personnel", etc.

Comment: the goal is to show in the combobox the value but want to save in a table the id who is a foreign key. How could I save the Id instead of the value??? Adding combobox is not editable.

Comment: Thanks all. I found what I was looking for. Only to put the result of the selected item into a variable and use this. int seletedPersonnelId =combopersonnel.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getNum_personnel();